# DJANGO - save html form data in xml file

Tags: xml, django, upload, save

I have an arbitrary html form that gathers user input and a file upload. What I do next is convert the input data to an xml object using [dicttoxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dicttoxml).

What i need to do next is define a storage directory on the server and upon every submit a new sub-directory is created, containing an xml file with the user input, and the uploaded file.

So far:

in urls:

```
url(r'newData', 'newData') //this actually points to the views file.
```

in views:

```
def newData(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    data = {
        'user': {
            'userName': request.user.username,
            'email': request.user.email
        },

        'info': {
            'message1': request.POST['message1'],
            'message2': request.POST['message2']
        }
    }

    xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(data, custom_root='newData', attr_type=False)
    return HttpResponse(xml, mimetype="application/xml")

return render_to_response('repository/editor/simple_form/new-data.html')
```

this actually returns the xml represantation of the data entered. What I am trying to do is "save" to xml file in specified directory.

```
<newData>
<info>
    <message1>message 1 here</message1>
    <message2>message 2 here</message2>
</info>
<user>
    <userName>username</user>
    <email>user@user.com</email>
</user>
```

Thanks...

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? FWIW it's so trivial that I just can't understand what your problem is : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Actually i don't know how to "save" the xml object to a file on the server...

Comment: do you have a model which will store the paths where the file will be uploaded?

Comment: XML is text, and a file is a file is a file, and "the server" is just the machine your code is running on (or any filesystem it can access).